# Xcode 8 - Building all schemes in background

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode-scheme

I use Xcode (8.2.1) schemes to build a project with different configurations :
[image]

Everytime time I change something in the code and hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to run the project, Xcode builds all the schemes :

[image]

AFAIK, this was not the case with Xcode 7. It is extremely heavy, and slows everything down ...

I disabled `Find Implicit Dependencies` in the schemes configuration, problem still.

Do you know a way to disable unselected schemes builds in background ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to disbla building unselected schemes in the background, but I noticed that it happens when using @IBDesignable classes (and it's a bug in XCode 8).
**Remove @IBDesignable from all of your custom views**, and it will probably stop having this behaviour. Just a quick fix before the bug is solved hopefully in XCode 9.